# Google App Script: How to set entire range of values to the PropertiesService and use JSON to extract and compare strings?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2X2 table that changes with an ImportRange function.

| Customer Name | Performance Status |
| --- | --- |
| Customer1 | performing |
| Customer2 | underperforming |

Using the following line I can set a property from a single cell:

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("A2",SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("A2").getValue());
```

How can I set a Property for a whole range (like A2:F100)? And then, how can I retrieve these properties values?

Comment: Why do you want property service? Are you going to use the values in some other function? If you explain what you want achieved, you can get suggestions.

Comment: Let's say that the table above gets updated from the ImportRange and the performance status changes from Performing to Underperforming. I want to be able to track this change.

The range changes through an ImportRange which means that I have to use the onChange trigger which doesn't hold the e.OldValue. 

I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH3U8869Jzg&lc=UgzBqlHR31OEBzvA9tt4AaABAg.9SaT3UqMP1-9SbI9X7WbqR&feature=em-comments)  that allows you to store the old value with onChange, but I cannot make it work for a whole range.

I hope that helps?

Comment: For your information onChange is not triggered by importRange. What you need can be acheived in the source data (from where you are pulling the performance data). When the performance changes in the source sheet, you can capture it by onEdit trigger function and do whatever you want. Please share the source sheet with some dummy values with public edit rights so that you will get a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function saveAll() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('All',JSON.stringify(vs));
}

function getAll(() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('All'))
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

This will only work on values that can be stringified.  Values such as dates will not be returned as dates.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving below a onEdit function which uses the old value in the cell.

You can try something similar to capture if a performer is becoming under performer or vice versa

```
//
//
function onEdit(e) {
var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
if(  activeSheet.getName()=="Sheet1" && activeCell.getColumn()== 11 ) {
  newValue=e.value;
  oldValue=e.oldValue;
  if(!e.value) {
    activeCell.setValue("");
  }else {
    if (!e.oldValue) {
      activeCell.setValue(newValue);
    }else {
      if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue) <0) {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue+','+newValue);
      }else {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
}
//
```

The above function makes a multi-select from a drop down - it adds values to a cell selected from a drop down (multiple items can be selected)